# Is there such a thing as Male and Female toilets?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

HELP! (First, This question could be a Dementia issue.)

This is about a 100+ yo house in San Francisco,CA. Gerty-The 96 yo. feisty woman who owns it is from the UK originally and has reverted to her native accent from a couple of strokes and the loss of her youngest son who was her primary caregiver during the long repair process. She blames her losses on the repairs and contractors involved.

The master bedroom and bath was added some time in the 1940s/1950s. The bathroom has 2 facing toilets and counters. one male and one female Toilets are the issue. They tried 1 round and 1 elongated, then 2 round and now 2 elongated.

This started by a dry rot repair and a sinking bathtub. That quickly turned into nearly 1/2 of the house and a complete overhaul of the all 2.5 bathrooms, kitchen, plumbing and power. The work looks Superb. Other then some paint issues and the male and female toilets the work is done.

I do not know what was removed from the bathroom. But has anyone heard of sexed toilets?

Comment: Other than female urinals, the only thing I can possibly come up with is a toilet with built in bidet.

Comment: I'm not sure what question you are asking. The customer may not always be right but if you want the money you may have to give them what they want, even if it makes no sense to you. If the two already existed, then that's what she wants and that's the end of it. Maybe both she and her husband were incontinent and needed access without risk of someone else being in the way.... But y'know, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: They become "ours" once we claim them. [How women think men use the toilet.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgTxebvkZYQ)

Comment: Sorry, bud, only crazy lady can answer this one for you. I think she's having flashbacks to an SNL skit: [The Love Toilet](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/the-love-toilet/n10153)

Comment: First, Comintern.We took her to look at Bidets,that was my idea too. No, she seems to be stressing 2 toilets with a difference of some kind in bowl size other then round and elongated.

Comment: Keshlam,Her late Husband has been gone for 8-10 years or so. Thus another reason this is so annoying. I'm trying to help a friend out by getting to the bottom of this.I ran my mouth thinking it was a simple issue of an elongated toilet and a round one.

Comment: It sounds like she is the only one who can tell you what she wants, and she is out if it and doesn't actually know what she wants. If that's really the case, the right answer may be to just tell her you don't understand the request and have to turn down the job. It isn't worth the time trying to satisfy an impossible request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about a UK bathroom (except it being called a Loo occasionally).

Try two signs. One for Ladies, one for Gents. The Gent's will be on the left-hand toilet, because the Women are always right..

Seriously, however... Does the owner have someone (often a relative) with power of attorney who can intercede for you and find out what you need to do in order to get paid for the work? Negotiating directly doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Pete, yeah, there is a huge fight in the family over the Power of Attorney for her. currently her Grandson is managing her. She had a lawsuit get thrown out for the second contractor who took over the job and finished it..